# set width to float div

Tags: css, html, width, css-float

I have a div that contains two other divs,, like this:

```
----------------------------
|            |             |   
|            |             |
| div 1      |    div 2    |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
----------------------------
```

div 1 has a fixed width and in same cases i need to remove it.
div 2 is always shown. The container of the two div has a fixed width.
My problem is how to define div2 width. If there is div1, div2 width has to be x but if the div1 is not shown, div2 width has to be the same of the container. Div1 and div2 have the  following css:

```
#div1{
    width: 146px;
    height: 118px;
    float: left;
}

#div2{
    height: 104px;
    padding: 12px 5px 2px 11px;
    float: left;
}
```

How can i do?

Comment: I think you will need to show more of your CSS and your html too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write like this:

**CSS**

```
#div1{
    width: 146px;
    height: 118px;
    float: left;
    background:red;
}

#div2{
    height: 104px;
    padding: 12px 5px 2px 11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/2zU3h/

Answer (score 0):

You can set width to "auto" of the div2 and also the min-width to "containerWidth-Div1Width".

Comment: it doesn't work to set div1 and div2 width to auto :(. Container width has a fixed width

Comment: Then you have to explicitly set the Div2's width equal to the container's width. And when it exists then you have to update its width using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JavaScript for this.

It can all be done using CSS.

Take a look at this snippet I just made:
http://jsfiddle.net/eUYyQ

Using the + selector, you can select the 2nd div and float it, if the 1st div is present. Otherwise the 2nd div will remain a block element.